# Show an alert to confirm Log out or not?

Tags: user-expectation, mobile-application, logout

I am currently working on a **iOS app** where users sign in.

However, I am curious to know what the best UX experience would be.

Would it best to show an alert to verify that they do want to log out or soon as they tap `Logout` should it straight away log them out?

Comment: Might be helpful https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40925/403790

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Just log out straight away**

It's not a *destructive action* as they can just log back in if they made a mistake.

They most likely will just want to log out so do it straight away rather than make the process longer than it needs to be.

Comment: I had put a confirmation dialogue encase they accidentally did tap on `Log Out`. But what you say does make sense and would be a better UX. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I would go with a confirmation only after the user logged out. I know many users tend to check if they really signed out of their account by relaunching the app.

Best practice is to do some A&B tests and see which one favors more.